# Nodejs/puppeteer - Navigation timeout error

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Can I resume connection after getting the error like that

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:    
TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout    
Exceeded: 1000ms exceeded
```

example:

```
 let arg = [] //array with urls
 await page.goto(...args, {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 1000 });
```

or the only way out is setup timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You want to do request to all urls in `args` array without stopping loop if one will fail.

So here is solution:

```
const async = require('async'); // npm i --save async

const urls = [... array of urls ...]; 
const execution = {
  total: urls.length,
  success: 0,
  failed: 0,
  results: []
};

async.eachLimit(
  urls, 
  10, 
  async (url, done) => {
    try {
      const data = await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 1000});
      execution.success++;
      execution.results.push({url, data});
    }
    catch (error) {
      execution.failed++;
      execution.results.push({url, data: null, error: error.message});
    }
    finally {
      done();
    }
  },
  (errors) => {
    console.log('Finished:', execution);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

**To answer the original question:**

No, you cannot resume connection after the `page.goto()` function times out. You can only handle the exception and perhaps retry.

On the other hand, if what you are trying to accomplish is to load a page,

**I suggest two changes to your code:**

**First:**

`page.goto()` does not accept an `Array` or an `Object` as the first argument, it needs to be a singular string, such as:

`page.goto('https://www.google.com')`.

[See docs](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&show=api-pagegotourl-options).

**Second:**

Unless the page you're loading is extremely simple, a `timeout` of 1000 ms is just too low. Puppeteer's default is 30000 ms, so I suggest either using that or setting a timeout of at least 5000 ms:

`page.goto('https://www.google.com', { timeout: 5000 })`

There's also no need to use `{ waitUntil: 'load' }` since that is the default value.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue comes from the argument you've supplied to the `goto` method of `puppeteer`:

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options

When you invoke `goto` it expects a `string` url and not `Array<string>`.